# How to change desktop background in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer, group-policy, desktop-customization

Due to **group policies** enforced on our systems, we can't change the **background of our desktop** permanently. The **IE**'s "Set as desktop background" is working but temporarily. 
PS: I have got administrator privileges to my system.

Comment: I'm sure @Ramhound means "This action requires being *an administrator* on the domain."

Comment: A secure domain is such an inconvenience for untrustworthy users…D’oh!

Comment: @Ramhound he doesn't mention if he's got a local or roaming profile, it's also possible that he's got a .man roaming profile. Mandatory profiles can't make permanent changes to system configuration.

Answer (score 1):

You would just find the background image file it is currently using and overwrite it, rather than trying to point your preferences at a different file.

So if your current background file is c:\windows\system\background.png, you would MAKE A BACKUP copy, background.png.bak or similar.  Then you would copy the one you want to use to c:\windows\system\background.png.  This will change the background for everyone who uses the computer, so you could instead make a script that copies the files on login/logout.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I think that his profile is a NTUser.man, which is called a mandatory profile (think read-only). These profiles can't make changes to the system configuration beyond the current session.

Comment: Could be right, but I assumed when he said he was an admin, he could modify system files.

Comment: yeah, that's weird.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same situation here. I've done it in a bit different way + does not require administrator privileges:

1. Create a new directory: **C:\Wallpaper**
2. Move to there your wallpaper, resize it to your screen dimensions and rename it to **background.jpg**. To resize the image without any 3rd party app, open background.jpg file with MS Paint, press CTRL+W (to resize), deselect "Keep aspect ratio", select "Pixels" radio button and adjust your image according to your desktop size.
3. Create new file in that directory named **wallpaper.bat** with the following content (note you can change 30 to a higher number if it fails to set on boot. For example: 60 or 90):

> ```
> timeout /t 30 /nobreak > NUL
> Call background.xlsm
> ```

4. Create **wallpaper.vbs** file in the same directory with the following content:

> ```
> Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell" ) 
> WshShell.Run chr(34) & "C:\Wallpaper\wallpaper.bat" & Chr(34), 0 
> Set WshShell = Nothing
> ```

5. Open MS Excel (later you will save it there, but now just follow the instructions), Press **Alt+F11** and Visual Basic for Applications will open. On the left side you should see project browser, so double click on **ThisWorkbook** and paste following content:

> ```
> Private Sub Workbook_Open()
>      If (ThisWorkbook.Name = "background.xlsm") Then
>           Call changeWallpaper("C:\Wallpaper\background.jpg")
>           Application.DisplayAlerts = False
>           Application.Quit
>      End If
> End Sub
> ```

6. In the same excel file, right click on any of the items in the project browser, then "Insert", then "Module" and paste the following code:

> ```
> Option Explicit
>
> Public Declare Function SystemParametersInfo Lib "user32" Alias
> "SystemParametersInfoA" _
>                     (ByVal uAction As Long, ByVal uParam As Long, _
>                      ByVal lpvParam As Any, ByVal fuWinIni As Long) As Long
>
> Public Const SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER = 20 Public Const
> SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE = &H2 Public Const SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE = &H1
>
> Public Sub changeWallpaper(location As String)
>
>      Dim strImagePath As String
>      strImagePath = location
>
>      Call SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0&, strImagePath, SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE Or SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE)
> End Sub
> ```

5. Make sure that macros are always available without confirmation to enable them for this file. Save this file as macros enabled Excel file with the extension **xlsm** (it is necesarry to name it background.xlsm):

> ```
> C:\Wallpaper\background.xlsm
> ```

7. Close and open **xlsm** Excel file. If wallpaper is being set - you are done. If not - check macros security. Maybe you need to add that excel file to a whitelist in Excel macros security settings? For me - it works. If you still can't get it working, - you are out of luck.
8. Set wallpaper on boot - in windows startup directory place the shortcut of **wallpaper.vbs** file. To make a shortcut, right click on wallpaper.vbs file and click "Create shortcut". To open startup directory, go to **Start** --> **All Programs** --> **startup** folder, then right click on it and "Open". Move your created shortcut to that startup directory.

**NOTE 1:** After booting up, 30secs will pass and your wallpaper should be set successful. Without the timer (30secs) the excel file will give error for some reason.

**NOTE 2:** To edit the Excel **xlsm** file, rename it to any other name (e.g. **bbackground.xlsm**) and open. When you done modifying content, save it and rename back to **background.xlsm**.